# Evaluatig a triple integral ( in Sphericals)

Tags: calculus, integration

Hi I dont have much experiance with spherical coordinates, but to me it seems as if the following problem requires it. The problem I am having is finding the limits of integration.

I want to solve $$\iiint_{R} (x^2+y^2)dV$$, where R is the region that lies above the cone $z=c\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ , and inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$

What I do know;

I know that in general we want to switch to $(\rho,\psi,\theta)$

where $z=\rho\cos(\psi)$,  $x=\rho\sin(\psi)\cos\theta$ and $y=\rho\sin\psi sin\theta$ and the Jacobian is $\rho^{2}\sin(\psi)$

I would think $\rho$ would go up to a.

For $\psi$ I think this will be determined by the cone, and $\theta$ should go from $0$ to $2pi$

and $\rho \cos \psi=c\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

But I am just not sure how to tie it all together, what terms to simplify, etc.

Looking for help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\rho\sin\psi\;$ gives $\;\rho\cos\psi=cr=c\rho\sin\psi$ on the cone,  so $\tan\psi=\frac{1}{c}$ on the cone.

Then $\displaystyle\iiint(x^2+y^2)dV=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{c}}\int_0^a(\rho\sin\psi)^2\rho^2\sin\psi \;d\rho d\psi d\theta$

$\hspace{1.45 in}\displaystyle=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{c}}\int_0^a\rho^4\sin^3\psi \;d\rho d\psi d\theta$

Comment: What is r? in this context

Comment: $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ represents the distance from the point $(x,y,z)$ to the z-axis.  (Equivalently, it is the distance from the projection of the point in the xy-plane to the origin.)

Comment: Hey, I am just wondering, how would I evaluate the psi integral from 0 to arctan(1/c), will it make sense to have a very weird expression?

Comment: @Quality If you use $\sin^3\psi=(1-\cos^2\psi)(\sin\psi)$ and $\cos(\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{c})=\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+1}}$, it should simplify to something pretty reasonable.